# Как сделать квадрат в обратном порядке ?

Tags: c, циклы

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size;
    int i, j;

    scanf("%d", &size);

    for (i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        for (j = size * size - (size - 1); j < size * size; j++) {

            printf("%d ", j);
        }

        printf("%dn", j);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Должен выводить при вводе 2

> `3 4
> 2 1`

при 4

> `13 14 15 16
> 9 10 11 12
> 5 6 7 8
> 1 2 3 4`

У меня просто получаются подряд все последние строки вот так

> `13 14 15 16
> 13 14 15 16
> 13 14 15 16
> 13 14 15 16`

Не могу понять, как мне вывести 2-ю 3-ю и последнюю.

Comment: а почему при 2 порядок обратный а при 4 прямой?

Comment: Прошу прощения, опечатка. Вот как должно выводить:
ввожу 2 выводит квадрат
3 4
2 1
ввожу 3 выводит квадрат
7 8 9
4 5 6
1 2 3
ввожу 4 выводит квадрат
13 14 15 16
9 10 11 12
5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4

Comment: и почему то в форме ввожу в виде квадрата (тут на форуме, а сохраняется как строки) (((

Comment: исправьте в в своём вопросе
чтобы сохранить форматирование в этом форуме надо в начало строки добавить пробелы
и перед блоком  таких строк должна быть пустая строка

 3 4
 2 1

    7 8 9
    4 5 6
    1 2 3
так?

Comment: Да, так. Исправила в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

запишите сначала в общем виде (обозначу n=size для краткости)

```
nn-n+1 ... nn
    ...
2n+1 ... 3n
n+1 ... 2n
1 ... n
```

Отсюда видно что внешний цикл по i нужен от n до 1 в обратном порядке,
а внутренний от i * n-n+1 до i * n в прямом порядке

Comment: Спасибо большое )) Заработало !! И понятно теперь стало ))

Comment: приятно :)

Answer (score 0):

Под "квадратом в обратном порядке", как я понял, имелась ввиду матрица с элементами расположенными по убыванию от максимального до 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size, max, first;
    int i, j;
    scanf("%d", &size);
    max = size*size;
    for(i=1; i<=size; i++)
    {
        first=max-size+1;
        for(j=1; j<=size; j++)
            printf("%d\t", first++);
        max-=size;
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: - Ну ответ же неправильный, и на учебные задания не стоит давать полные ответы. Нужно не чтобы человек выполнил задание но чтобы он научился.

Comment: Ну вот сразу бы кто-нибудь и написал, что неправилен. Я ведь в своём сообщении сделал пометку о том, как я понял суть вопроса. Оказалось, не совсем верно. Да и топикстартер сделала уточнения в комментариях. Теперь выходит верно:
  7 8 9
  4 5 6
  1 2 3